# How to create multiple draggable objects using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm trying to create multiple draggable objects using html and javascript. This tutorial [http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/] only shows draggable functionality for one object. My goal is to create multiple (for ex: 11 objects that can move around a canvas.

this is the code I have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Team Management; Soccer</title>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
    </style>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0…"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0…"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="squad.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //pen tool styling 

        var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
            prevX = 0,
            currX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            currY = 0,
            dot_flag = false;

        var x = "blue",
            y = 5;

        function init() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('can');
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            w = canvas.width;
            h = canvas.height;

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                findxy('move', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
                findxy('down', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
                findxy('up', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
                findxy('out', e)
            }, false);
        }

        function color(obj) {
            switch (obj.id) {
            case "red":
                x = "red";
                break;
            case "blue":
                x = "blue";
                break;
            case "orange":
                x = "orange";
                break;
            case "yellow":
                x = "yellow";
                break;
            }
            if (x == "white") y = 14;
            else y = 5;

        }

        function draw() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
            ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
            ctx.strokeStyle = x;
            ctx.lineWidth = y;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function erase() {
            var m = confirm("Want to clear");
            if (m) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function save() {
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
        }

        function findxy(res, e) {
            if (res == 'down') {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

                flag = true;
                dot_flag = true;
                if (dot_flag) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = x;
                    ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    dot_flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
                flag = false;
            }
            if (res == 'move') {
                if (flag) {
                    prevX = currX;
                    prevY = currY;
                    currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                    currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                    draw();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">SQUAD SPOT</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Corina/Downloads/bootstrap/simple-      sidebar/squad_spot_field.html">Field</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Corina/Downloads/bootstrap/simple-sidebar/squad_spot_roster1.html">Roster</a>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Page content header-->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-header">
                <h1 style="position:absolute; left:18%;"><td><!--<div id="edit"  contenteditable="true">--><strong><font color="white">LA United</font></strong></div>
<img height="550" width="1075" src="http://www.7rt.org/wp- content/uploads/2013/01/Wallpapers-wit…" style="position:absolute;top: 73px;left: 268px;  border: 5px solid white"/>
<canvas id="can" width="1073" height="548" style="position:absolute;top: 73px;left: 268px;border:2px solid green;"></canvas>
<div style="position:absolute;top:13px;right:58%;"><font color="brown" size="6">     <strong><em>Pen Tool</em></strong></font></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 6%;right:55%;width:30px;height:30px;background:red;"  id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 1%;right:55%;width:30px;height:30px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)">    </div>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 6%;right:52.5%;width:30px;height:30px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 1%;right:52.5%;width:30px;height:30px;background:yellow;" id="yellow"  onclick="color(this)"></div> 


<div id="container" style="position:absolute; left:271px;top:78px;opacity:.8;">
<script defer="defer">
//box 
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: 1070,
height: 540,

});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
x: 100,
y: 40,
width: 50,
height: 50,
fill: '#00d2ff',
stroke: 'black',
strokeWidth: 4,
draggable: true
});

// add cursor styling
box.on('mouseover', function() {
document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
box.on('mouseout', function() {
document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});

layer.add(box);
stage.add(layer);
</script> 
</div>


<!-- <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;right:78%;"><font color="red">Eraser</font>   </div>-->
<!--<div  style="position:absolute;top:22%;right:80%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2 px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>-->
<img id="canvasing" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
<input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()"  style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
<input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="15" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:18px;right: 48.5%; font-size: 100%;">




<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JavaScript for the Menu Toggle -->

<style type="text/css">
input {
border:1px solid black; 
line-height:10px;
height:40px;
}
body{
background-image:url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-l_EB71-   DFZA/TmAaWO3I3UI/AAAAAAAAC7M/dYdeW0W7kIw/s1600/1314270613188.jpg");
background-size: 1400px 900px;
background-repeat: no repeat;

}

</style> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Kinetic.js, a framework for doing interactivity in the canvas.

From looking at the Kinetic.js documentation, I think if you just add multiple Kinetic.Rect to the scene, you'll have multiple objects. Might I suggest a for loop:

```
var boxes = [],
    box;
for (var i = 0, l = 11; i < l; ++i) {
    box = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: i * 55 + 100, // space out your boxes horizontally
        y: 40,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#00d2ff',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    box.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    box.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    layer.add(box);
    boxes.push(box); // keep track of a reference to your box
}
```